# redhat 7 + How to stop systemctl service permanent

Tags: rhel, services, systemctl

we are install some service on redhat 7

but for now we no need the service application anymore

is it possible to disable the start of the service?

I not mean to disable it on the next reboot
what we mean is to avoid starting the service , in spite service installed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`systemctl disable servicename`.

Running `systemctl disable` removes the symlink to the service in `/etc/systemd/system/*`.

From now on, that service won't start on boot anymore.

Comment: `stop` service first then `disable`. In my case service after 'diabled' was still restarting until I restarted PC

Answer (score 9):

There is also a stronger version of the `disable` command, which is `mask`. From the [manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#mask%20UNIT%E2%80%A6):

> `mask UNIT…`
>
> Mask one or more units, as specified on the command line. This will link these unit files to `/dev/null`, making it impossible to start
>   them. This is a stronger version of disable, since it prohibits all
>   kinds of activation of the unit, including enablement and manual
>   activation. Use this option with care. This honors the `--runtime`
>   option to only mask temporarily until the next reboot of the system.
>   The `--now` option may be used to ensure that the units are also
>   stopped. This command expects valid unit names only, it does not
>   accept unit file paths.

While `systemctl disable unit` would prevent a unit from starting on the next boot, you could still start the unit manually. `systemctl mask unit` prevents the unit from being started either automatically or manually. It does so by overriding the unit file with a symlink to `/dev/null`.

Finally, the command to reverse the effects of `mask` is `unmask`: `systemctl unmask unit`.

Comment: this is exactly what I need since the service is controlled by puppet which starts it "manually".